# Download folder from the Artifactory repo using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, artifactory

I am using the following code to download files from Artifactory using PowerShell.

```
#example Artifactory url
 $artifactory_url = "https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/"
 #example Artifactory Key
 $ArtifactoryKey = "<artifactory key>" 

 $wc = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
 $wc.Headers.Add("X-JFrog-Art-Api", $ArtifactoryKey)
 $files = @("test1.zip", "test.zip") 
 try {
   foreach($file in $files) {
     $wc.DownloadFile("$artifactory_url/$file", "D:\download\$file")
   }
 }
 catch {
    $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine("Error while Trying to download Artifacts.")
    $Host.UI.WriteErrorLine($_.Exception.Message)
    exit
 }
```

I now have a repository on Artifactory that has couple of recursive folders with files. So I need to download all contents of that repository.

What do I need to change in my code above to achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

To [download the entire folder](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-DownloadingFiles) under a repository you can utilize the [JFrog CLI](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory). First, configure the Artifactory with the JFrog CLI and download the entire folder as below,

```
$ jfrog rt dl "my-local-repo/*.jar" all-my-frogs/
```